# Closed solution to ${1\over \sqrt {4-x^2}} = 1- {1 \over \sqrt{9-x^2}}$?

Tags: polynomials

Of course I can solve this numerically but is there a way to have an exact solution? The equation is the solution to this problem: we have an alley, we lean a 2m long ladder to one wall, a 3m long ladder to the other wall, the two ladders meet each other 1m high, how wide is the alley.

Edit: let ABC a right angled triangle with the right angle at A. Let ABD another right angle triangle with the right angle at B. BC is 2, AD is 3.  The crossing point of BC and AD is E. The distance of AB to E is 1. How long is AB?

Comment: The answer is $\sqrt {3^2-1^2}+\sqrt{2^2-1^2}$ - no need for quadratic equation.

Comment: Alpha finds a mess with $x \approx \pm1.23119.  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fsqrt%284-x%5E2%29%2B1%2Fsqrt%289-x%5E2%29-1) is the graph, showing these answers as well as the above.

Comment: @A.S. that result is impossibly large, it can't be more than 2.

Comment: Specifically, [these](http://i.imgur.com/LFsXybj.png) are the closed solutions.

Comment: @AndreyKaipov ouch. Any clue as to how to get to those? I bet it won't be easy. And one wonders, of course, whether there's a simpler form of that.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the statement of the problem. Drop perpendicular from the point of meeting of the ladders to the floor. The first term in my sum is projection of the first ladder onto the floor, the second - of the second. Adding them up give the distance.

Comment: Please rewrite it using names for point or draw a picture.

Comment: Let the first term be $1/a$ and  the last $1/b$. Then $a+b=ab$ and $b^2-a^2=5$. Substitute $a$ from the first equation into the second to get 4th degree polynomial in $b$ which can be solves explicitly. That will give you $x$ explicitly.

Comment: Edited, hope it's clearer.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crossed_ladders_problem